# How to use fgets() and store every line of a file using an array of char pointers?

Tags: file, pointers, fgets, arrays

I wrote the program below in order to read every line of the file and then store each line in a array of char pointers for later use (like sorting only the pointers not the real strings). **But the problem is that it keeps storing the same line.**

Lets say that the file is called *file.txt* and has two(2) lines with text.

```
  first sentence
  second sentence
```

The code I wrote is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    FILE *cf;
    cf = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char line[101];
    char *lines[2];
    char *eof;

    int i=0;
    while((eof = fgets(line, 101, cf)) != NULL){
        lines[i] = eof;
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", lines[0]);
    printf("%s\n", lines[1]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
second sentence
second sentence
```

But I want to get:

```
first sentence
second sentence
```

What I am doing wrong here?

-Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `fgets` **doesn't allocate new memory**. So in case of success `eof == line` - that's right, it returns what you passed. You are overwriting it every time.

Try:

```
while((eof = fgets(line, 101, cf)) != NULL){
    lines[i] = strdup(eof);
    i++;
}
```

Of course you must remember to `free(lines[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), e.g.

```
char* myline = NULL;
size_t mylinesize = 0;
ssize_t mylinelen = 0;
while ((mylinelen = getline(&myline, &mylinesize, cf)) >= 0) {  
    lines[i++] = strdup(myline);
}
free (myline); 
myline = NULL;
```

and you should consider using [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) and the [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library ([GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) licensed) for interactive use.

Answer (score 0):

```
eof = fgets(line, 101, cf)
while(eof!=NULL)
{
    puts(eof);
    eof=fgets(line,101,cf);
    free(eof);
}
```