# Coping a Line from a File to Array (C)

Tags: c, arrays

Given a file with information sorted by line, I'm asked to write a program to store each line in a string.

```
This is the first line. 
This is the second line. 
This is the third line.
This is the fourth line.
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 70
#define NLine 4
int main()
{
    FILE *arq;
    char line[MAX];
    char *eof;
    char name[20];
    char *nline[NLine];
    int i;
    printf("\nGive me the name of the file: ");
    fgets(name, 20 , stdin);
    arq = fopen(name, "r");
    while( ( eof = fgets(line, MAX, arq ) )!= NULL )
        {
            nline[i] = strdup(eof);
            i++;
        }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NLine; i++)
        printf("%s", nline[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < NLine; i++)
        free( nline[i] );
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

My output is a segmentation fault; but when I substitute `arq = fopen(name, "r");` for `arq = fopen("test.txt", "r");` the program runs perfectly. I execute `gdb` and it has returned

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a7ea2b in fgets () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Is it wrong to call `fopen` with an array of strings as a parameter, or did I do something wrong in the program?

Also I would like to know how the part

```
    while( ( eof = fgets(line, MAX, arq ) )!= NULL )
        {
            nline[i] = strdup(eof);
            i++;
        }
```

works. I just saw the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920932/how-to-use-fgets-and-store-every-line-of-a-file-using-an-array-of-char-pointer) and managed it to work; but I did not understand how the function read another line instead of keeping reading the same line, for there is no apparent change in how the `eof` is read from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialise your pointers in the `nline` array.  You need to set each one to NULL.  Otherwise, when you come along and free them later, you will have undefined behaviour.

```
for( i = 0; i < NLine; i++ ) nline[i] = NULL;
```

Alternatively, you can save the number of lines that you read in and only free that many values, instead of all `NLine` of them.  You should probably do this, because you need to do the same when you print the values out.  You'll want to have a count.  I've used `line_count` here.

```
for( i = 0; i < line_count; i++ ) free(nline[i]);
```

You have potential buffer overflow when you read the lines in.  You need to make sure your array indices stay in range:

```
line_count = 0;
while( line_count < NLine && fgets(line, MAX, arq) )
    nline[i++] = strdup(line);
```

And yet another thing, as pointed out by the user *Myforwik*, `fgets` leaves the line separator character in the string, and you must remove it yourself when you read in the file name:

```
if( fgets(name, 20 , stdin) ) {
    /* Remove line terminator(s) if any: iscntrl() from ctype.h is okay */
    for( i = strlen(name)-1; i >= 0 && iscntrl(p[i]); i-- ) p[i] = '\0';
} else {
    name[0] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fgets will include a carrage return in name, so you are trying to open a file that has a carriage return at the end of the name, which will fail. Since you never check if the program successfully opened the file, the next fgets will be undefined behaviour.

For a start you need to add: `if (!arq) { printf("could not open file"); return; }` after you attempt fopen.

The other part is simple, it is assigns eof to the output of fgets, then if compares eof to null.

Also you have massive other problems. char *eof; does not allocate room for a string. it allocates a pointer only. you probably want something like `char *eof; eof = malloc(1024);` You also have this problem with your array of lines. You need to allocate memory to each line. You can't just copy the string to a point - those points need to point to some memory first.

Comment: *"char *eof; does not allocate room for a string"* -- Have you never used `strdup` before?

Comment: @Myforwik, I just added `if (!arq) { printf("could not open file"); return; }` after my attempt to open the file, and now my output is always `could not open file`. Also, I did initiate each `nline[i]` with `malloc ( 20 * sizeof (char) )`  and initialize each `nline[i]` with `NULL` as @paddy has suggested.

Comment: I did *not* suggest that.

Comment: Sorry @paddy, I just fixed my comment.

Comment: What Myforwik is trying to tell you is that you should remove the newline from the string you read in.  Simply start at `strlen(name)-1` and set characters to 0 while they are `'\n'`, `'\r'` or `'\f'`.

Comment: @paddy, I did not understand what should I do. Please, could you expand your answer.